# Threads and string literals

Tags: c++, multithreading, string-literals

Is it valid (defined behavior) to access a string literal simultaneously with multiple threads? Given a function like this:

```
const char* give()
{
  return "Hello, World!";
}
```

Would it be save to call the function and dereference the pointer simultaneously?

Edit: Many answers. Will accept the first one who can show me the section out of the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the standard:

> C++11 1.10/3: The value of an object visible to a thread T at a particular point is the initial value of the object, a value assigned to the object by T, or a value assigned to the object by another thread, according to the rules below.

A string literal, like any other constant object, cannot legally be assigned to; it has static storage duration, and so is initialised before the program starts; therefore, all threads will see its initial value at all times.

Older standards had nothing to say about threads; so if your compiler doesn't support the C++11 threading model then you'll have to consult its documentation for any thread-safety guarantees. However, it's hard to imagine any implementation under which access to immutable objects were not thread-safe.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's safe. Why wouldn't it be? It would be unsafe if you'd try to modify the string, but that's illegal anyway.

Comment: You might add a reminder that string literals have static lifetime, so they are created before the program starts, and live until it ends; possible issues concerning construction cannot occur either.

Comment: Do you know in which section of the standard those things (read access with threads) are defined? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @cooky451 I doubt you'll find anything in the standard concerning this.

Comment: lol why wouldn't I? And if you don't know any of the thread section, how could you answer the question? If it isn't there, it is UB.

Comment: @cooky451 there are lots of things that are not in the standard but are not UB.

Comment: @cooky451: The relevant section is C++11 1.10/3: "The value of an object visible to a thread T at a particular point is the initial value of the object, a value assigned to the object by T, or a value assigned to the object by another thread, according to the rules
below." Since no thread can assign to a string literal, all threads will see its initial value at any point.

Comment: @MikeSeymour is this new to C++11? I couldn't find any reference in the previous version and, AFAIK, the standard didn't deal with thread (until the last version, I see).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Yes, earlier standards had nothing to say about threads.

Answer (score 2):

It is always safe to access immutable data from multiple threads. String literals are an example of immutable data (since it's illegal to modify them at run-time), so it is safe to access them from multiple threads.

Comment: ... Always safe *after* construction completes and *before* destruction starts (which is undefined behavior anyway)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you only read data, you can access it from as many threads as you want. When data needs to be changed, that's when it gets complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the implementation of the C Compiler. But I do not know of an implementation where concurrent read accesses might be unsafe, so in practice this is safe.

Answer (score 0):

String literals are (conceptually) stored in read only memory and initialised on loading (rather than at runtime). It's therefore safe to access them from multiple threads at any time.

Note that more complex structures might not be initialised at load time, and so multiple thread access might have the possibility of issues immediately after the creation of the object.

But string literals are completely safe.